# How to quickly set a relative height to lots of elements

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using this code to set a relative height to many divs:

```
$("#output div").each(function (index) {
    $(this).css({ "height": ($(this).height() * multiplier) + "px" });
});
```

This is a very expensive operation.  Is there any way to optimize this for speed?

Setting an absolute height, like this:

```
$("#output div").css({ "height": "20px" });
```

Is extremely fast.  Sadly I don't need absolute values, but relative to a multiplier.

--

EDIT:

I'm constantly adding these divs with an unknown height.  Something like this:

```
$("#output div:first").remove();
$("#output").append("<div class=\"output-column\" style=\"height: " + 40 * Math.random() + "px;\">&nbsp;</div>");
```

So basically it's a chart with, lets say 1000 divs, popping at the left and pushing in at the right (they are 1 pixel wide).  What I need is for these divs to dynamically change their hight relative to the tallest div.  So the tallest div take up the parent's height and the others adjust their height accordingly.  So if a div enters that have 120% height then it have to be adjusted to 100% and the others 20% relative down.

Comment: Do all your divs have the same height? If so, then just calculate the new height once and store it in a variable. If each of your divs has a different height, then you have to calculate the new height for each one individually.

Comment: They are different and have an "unknown" height.

Comment: What is the bigger picture? Why are you doing this? Can you use a more specific selector such as `#output > div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is most likely not the javascript (though I can't be sure without knowing what you are doing). The problem is that each time you set the height of a single element in that loop, the browser will re-calculate the layout. So if you have 1000 elements, it will recalculate the layout 1000 times, when what you really need is to set all the heights first then recalculate the layout after all have been set.

How do you do this? With document fragments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment .

The reason the absolute positioned elements are so much faster is because absolute elements do not effect the positioning of any other elements on the page. They 'float' above them, so much less layout re-calculation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value

In your case it would be:

```
$("#output div").css("height", function(index, value) {
  return value * multiplier + "px";
});
```